# How to interpolate variable within object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, properties

I have this part of an object :

```
js: {
    cwd: 'src/js',
    src: [ "src/js/*.js", "src/js/*.min.js" ],
    dest: 'dist/js'
}
```

How can I insert the `cwd` property into `src` property so it looks like the following?

```
src: [ `${cwd (or js.cwd)}/*.JS .. etc ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a computed property so use a getter.

```js
const js = {
    cwd: 'src/js',
    get src() {
      return [ "/*.js", "/*.min.js" ]
        .map(ending => this.cwd + ending)
     },
    dest: 'dist/js'
}

console.log(js)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the **[`Array#shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)**, **[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) methods** like this:

```
js = [js].map(a => {
  a.src.push(a.cwd);
  delete a.cwd;
  return a;
}).shift();
```

**Demo:**

```js
var js = {
  cwd: 'src/js',
  src: ["src/js/*.js", "src/js/*.min.js"],
  dest: 'dist/js'
};

js = [js].map(a => {
  a.src.push(a.cwd);
  delete a.cwd;
  return a;
}).shift();

console.log(js);
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES2018' [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
const foo = {
    ...js,
  src: [...js.src, js.cwd]
}
```